# Kendo TreeView sequence contains no elements error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, treeview, kendo-ui

While using a Kendo TreeView with server side data, I'm having an issue while binding data in MVC.

My controller action is:

```
public ActionResult DayPart(long storeid)
{
    IEnumerable<TreeViewMapModel> objDaypart = 
        from item in new DayPartService().GetAll().ToList()
        select new TreeViewMapModel
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name,
            Items = (from map in new DayPartMappingService().GetByStoreId(storeid)
                     where item.Id == map.DayPartId
                     select new MasterModel()
                     {
                        Id = int.Parse(map.SourceId),
                        Name = map.SourceLabel 
                     }).ToList(),
        };

    var ret = objDaypart.Select(x => new TreeViewMapModel
    {
        HasChildren = x.Items.Count() > 0,
        Id = x.Id,
        Items = x.Items ?? Enumerable.Empty<MasterModel>(),
        Name = x.Name
    });
    
    @ViewBag.storename = new StoreService().GetById(storeid).Name;
    
    return View(ret);
}
```

And in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Apis.Web.MvcPortal.Areas.Setups.Models.TreeViewMapModel>

@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("right-treeview")
    .BindTo(Model.ToList(), (Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.NavigationBindingFactory<TreeViewItem> mappings) =>
    {
        mappings.For<Apis.Web.MvcPortal.Areas.Setups.Models.TreeViewMapModel>(bound => bound
            .ItemDataBound((node, structure) =>
            {
                node.HasChildren = structure.HasChildren;
                node.Id = structure.Id.ToString();
                node.Text = structure.Name;
            })
            .Children(structure => structure.Items)
        );
    })
)
```

But I am getting an error saying "sequence contain no elements". Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

My stacktrace is:

> ```
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
> at Kendo.Mvc.UI.NavigationItemContainerExtensions.Bind[TNavigationItem](TNavigationItem component, Object dataItem, NavigationBindingFactory`1 factory)
> at Kendo.Mvc.UI.NavigationItemContainerExtensions.Bind[TNavigationItem](TNavigationItem component, Object dataItem, NavigationBindingFactory`1 factory)
> at Kendo.Mvc.UI.NavigationItemContainerExtensions.BindTo[TNavigationItem](INavigationItemContainer`1 component, IEnumerable dataSource, Action`1 factoryAction)
> at Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.TreeViewBuilder.BindTo(IEnumerable dataSource, Action`1 factoryAction)
> at ASP._Page_Areas_Setups_Views_Mapping_DayPart_cshtml.Execute() in d:\APISBI_MVC\APISBI\Main\SRC\Apis.Web.MvcPortal\Areas\Setups\Views\Mapping\DayPart.cshtml:line 47
> at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
> at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
> at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
> at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
> at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
> at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
> at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
> at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
> at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
> ```

Comment: TreeViewMapModel is a ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when the Children's object datatypes were not also converted to the same  type that is being passed to the grid.

For example, in my case what came from the service was a List which I converted to a more generic List -- but the children sitting on each Tag were still tags.

I either needed a recursive function to convert the child Tags to OurTreeItemClass or alternatively, to create a service method that returns this data as OurTreeItemClass in the first place to alleviate the need to do these conversions at all.